# Movement of Cash after UK Visa application submission

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, money, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have applied for a UK Visa. In my application I notified that an **X** amount in my Bank Statement is for a provisional booking for a Car in my home country.(Booking confirmation receipt was also attached with the Bank Statement) 
The application has been submitted and I am waiting for a response.

I have been notified by the dealer that I can submit the full amount and get the car for an additional amount **Y**.

**Question:**

1. Is it OK for me to make this transaction without jeopardizing my
   chances of getting a Visa?
2. Can the British embassy check records
   for individuals after submission of an application? Or do they just review the statements submitted (If they do then they would not
   know why I pulled the funds)

**Note:** I have applied for a Business Visit funded by my company. **Y** is a good percentage.

Comment: They might check if they have doubt. If you can deposit money then deposit some to equal the amount.

Comment: What is "provisional booking for a car"? Do you mean you are buying a car?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it OK for me to make this transaction without jeopardizing my
>   chances of getting a Visa?

YES

> Can the British embassy check records for individuals after submission
>   of an application? Or do they just review the statements submitted (If
>   they do then they would not know why I pulled the funds)

YES, they can and sometimes do

The ECO does not expect that your account should be static while waiting for a visa approval. Life is dynamic and that is how it should be. You are not going to be denied a visa because after application you had to move some money.

Read [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and if you have no red flags mentioned, you are fine.

Comment: I was uncomfortable because the amount is a good percentage...

Comment: If you read the excellent article I linked to, you would realize the I/O is looking at the activity in your account over a period of time, not just the current amount. Submit 3-6 months of statements should give a good picture of your financial situation. However if still you want to delay the purchase of the car it's up to you.